# svg - flip upside down ex. graph

Tags: css, html, svg

I'm trying to work out a simple svg example - creating bar graph.
However, I don't have clear grasp of how it works. I rotated an existing graph
upside down but seems like there is a small offset. Corresponding jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/rhvP8/2/

```
  <div style="width:300px;height:300px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width:100%;height:100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <g>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="40%" x="0" y="0" fill="black"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="20%" x="50" y="0" fill="green"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="80%" x="100" y="0" fill="red"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="90%" x="150" y="0" fill="yellow"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="10%" x="200" y="0" fill="pink"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="60%" x="250" y="0" fill="orange"></rect>
    </g>
</svg> 
</div>
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width:100%;height:100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <g transform="rotate(180)">
        <rect  width="14.55" height="40" x="-50" y="-300" fill="black"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="20" x="-100" y="-300" fill="green"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="35" x="-150" y="-300" fill="red"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="90" x="-200" y="-300" fill="yellow"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="10" x="-250" y="-300" fill="pink"></rect>
        <rect  width="14.55" height="60" x="-300" y="-300" fill="orange"></rect>
    </g>
    </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: with 180 degree rotation, the bottom right corner co-ords are -300,-300 and bottom left co-ords are 0,-300. if width were 50 then
the box appears properly aligned. since width is only 14.55, it starts at x=-50 and continues upto -35.45 hence the offset.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need to remember is that the `rotate()` transform will rotate an object about the coordinates (0,0), which in this case is the top left corner of the graph. Since the graph is 300p wide and 300px tall, rotating through 180° causes the graph to spin off beyond the top left corner. A `translate` transform can be used to readjust the coordinates so that the drawing appears within the viewbox again. Hopefully this illustration will explain:

[image: Illustration of rotate and translate transforms in an SVG]

Here's an updated JSfiddle with a few other fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/rhvP8/4/

Comment: I like translate but the graph is swapped i.e. first bar - the black one - becomes the last one.

Comment: sƃuıɥʇ ǝʇɐʇoɹ noʎ uǝɥʍ suǝddɐɥ ʇɐɥʍ s,ʇɐɥʇ

Comment: right, so is there any other better way to draw a graph ? because,
now if i use same logic for a line graph it would be inverted

Comment: Can we backtrack a bit here? Why are you drawing this thing upside down in the first place?

Comment: I'm new to svg. All i am looking to do is draw a bar graph. I thought it would be easier using straightforward x y values and turning it upside down. may be that is not the right way to do ?

Comment: Oh, I see. What you wanted to do was scale the graph vertically by a negative value. Here's another JSFiddle that shows how you can plot a graph of y = sin x using actual values from 0 to 2π. The important bit is in the parent `<g>` tag: `transform="translate(5 100) scale(60 -60)"`. The graph is scaled up a lot, so the line widths are very small. And the text has to be in a separate group, otherwise it will be reflected too. http://jsfiddle.net/AdbPE/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to squeamish's solution is just to use the version of rotate that takes the rotation origin as well: `rotate(angle x y)`.

Since you know your graph is 300x300, using `rotate(180 150 150)` works fine.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rhvP8/5/)

Comment: Instead of the rotation being about the origin (0,0), the point (x,y) will be used as the centre of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: *the **scaleY()** CSS function, defines a transformation that resizes an element along the y-axis (vertically).*

```
svg {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

View browser compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleY()#browser_compatibility